# jQuery Lightbox plugin not working on my page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I have spent hours on this problem. Here is my code.

```
<div id="contentBox">
 <p>Some text here </p>
<div id="photoAlbumOne">
  <ul id="photoAlbum">
    <li id="fig1"><a href="../images/image1.png"><img src="../images/thumb1.png"></a></li>
    <li id="fig2"><a href="../images/image2.png"><img src="../images/thumb2.png"></a></li>
  </ul>  
</div>
</div>
```

Here is script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#photoAlbumOne a').lightBox();
  });
</script>
```

I have given the link to both jQuery and and plugins. What's wrong? Why is it not working? I appreciate your help.

Comment: 1. Add alert($('#contentBox a').length); for further information.
2. Check if lightBox is loaded - alert($.lightBox); - must return function code

More information required to answer.

Comment: Then the plugin-link is wrong. After that change you should replace the 2nd id `fig1` with something else, because ids have to be unique.

Comment: fig1 was my mistake here. Now I have changed. Yes, it is linked it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

could you please confirm used this "#photoAlbumOne" in light box css.